# Компиляция xcode с универсальной архитектурой i386, x86_64 с имеющимися файлами Assembler

Tags: c++, xcode, ассемблер

Добрый день друзья! Помогите пожалуйста решить такую проблему. 
Хочу создать динамическую библиотеку с универсальной архитектурой на Xcode, Имею два файла с Ассемблерной реализацией одной функции: одна для платформы i386 другая для x86_64. По отдельным архитектурам всё строится а вот вместе - никак, ибо i386 гавкает на 64-битные регистры. [image: building]

я делал так на c++:

```
#if !__LP64__
extern "C" void func32(); // prototype
 #endif

#if __LP64__
extern "C" void func64(); // prototype
 #endif 
...................
#if !__LP64__
func32(); 
 #endif

#if __LP64__
func64(); 
 #endif
```

Кроме того включены в проект файлы реализации функций: file32.s & file64.s

Comment: По возможности избегайте ссылок на картинки и публикуйте просто техт. Вы же не можете гарантировать, что картинка не будет удалена с сервера и ваша ссылка не станет битой.

Comment: Кроме Xсode у вас где-нибудь получалось так сделать?

Comment: Честно говоря кроме xcode и Visual studio я с другим не сталкивался. На VS я и не пытался я думаю там такой возможности нет. Столкнувшись с XCode я увидел что в нём можно собирать для двух архитектур одновременно.